# Recover backed-up linked email account after factory reset

Tags: gmail, accounts

I had previously linked a office 365 account to my gmail app. Due to reasons, this office account got blocked and I no longer have access to it, but I still could see all the emails that had been synced to my phone.

Today I decided to do a factory reset as I had some problems with the phone. I have checked the settings of this office account in the gmail app, and it stated that it was backed up. So I proceeded to do the factory reset. Now I have re-linked my phone to my gmail account, all apps have been reinstalled, but the office 365 account that was supposed to be backed up is no-where to be found.

Is there any way to recover the emails or sync this office account from the backups?

Comment: guesswork, backup just stored email login credentials because typically emails are stored on the email server anyway

Comment: yeah that is what I though as well... But they should be more clear about it.